# Use in_array() in if statement returns false in a loop that results in "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am developing my own Twitter-style social media for a school project.
I code in PHP and store users, posts and followers in MYSQL tables (my variable names are in swedish so therefore they are called: anvandare, inlagg and foljningar)

So now I want to just show post from those I am following. I decided to fetch all userIDs of those I follow and store them in an array.

```
$sqlfoljer="select foljarid, foljdid from foljningar where foljarid =$anvandarID";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlfoljer);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

if (!$row)
{
    echo "You are not following anyone.";
    die();
}

$foljer = array();

while ($row != null)
{
    array_push($foljer, $row['foljdid']);

$row = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

I fetch all posts in one query and then I check if the person who wrote them are in my array of the people I follow

```
 $sql = "select id, datumskapat, text, bild, anvandarID, namnAnvandare from inlagg order by datumskapat desc";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

if (!$row)
{
    exit();
}

while ($row != null)
{
    $anvandarID = $row['anvandarID'];
    $inlaggsid = $row['id'];

    if(in_array($anvandarID, $foljer))
    {
        $sqlgillar = "select count(*) as antalgillar from gillningar where inlaggsid = :inlaggsid";

        $params2 = array(':inlaggsid'=>$row['id']);

        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sqlgillar);

        $stmt2->execute($params2);

        $row = $stmt2->fetch();


            if ($bild != null)
            {
                //Lägg tll bild
                echo "<img src=\"visabild.php?id=$inlaggsid\" alt=\"Bild\" />";
            }

            }
                            $row = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        else
        {
            echo"You dont follow this person";
        }
    }
```

Alright, so the problem is that this does not work. When I enter the page in the browser it feels like it freeze, but it just takes a verry long time and then I get the Fatal error of Maximum time.

The posts are not loaded correctly. It is just posts from one person (the first personID in the array). I added an else-statement for the in_array and it echos "You dont follow this person" like infinitly many times until the 30 second break.

Can someone find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: alot of those code seems irrellevent to the question. Please be sure to always ask your questions *simply* on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get all posts and when check its author if you follow them. It takes too log time. Instead you should ask database to do this work .
You can help your database and add index on field `anvandarID` which prevent seq scan over the whole table and significantly improve query speed and efficiency.

You should add `WHERE anvandarID IN ()` condition into your query for post selecting:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($foljer) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "select id, datumskapat, text, bild, anvandarID, namnAnvandare from inlagg 
    WHERE anvandarID IN ($in) order by datumskapat desc";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($in_array);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you. I just changed to just fetch()